# How to disable logging in dmesg (/proc/kmsg) for specific device/driver?

Tags: logging, linux-kernel, dmesg

I am using a TechnoTrend TT-connect S2-3600 which is known for spamming dmesg (respectively /proc/kmsg) with the following errors:

```
[ 8360.122449] pctv452e: I2C error -121; AA A1  CC 00 01 -> 55 a1 31 03 cc 00 00
[ 8360.135079] pctv452e: I2C error -121; AA B8  CC 00 01 -> 55 b8 31 03 cc 00 00
[ 8360.202210] pctv452e: I2C error -121; AA D4  CC 00 01 -> 55 d4 31 03 cc 00 00
[ 8360.936229] pctv452e: I2C error -121; AA 42  CC 00 01 -> 55 42 31 03 cc 00 00
[ 8360.951637] pctv452e: I2C error -121; AA 59  CC 00 01 -> 55 59 31 03 cc 00 00
[ 8361.019133] pctv452e: I2C error -121; AA 75  CC 00 01 -> 55 75 31 03 cc 00 00
```

Since the I2C error won't get fixed, what can I do to avoid spamming of dmesg? Is there any option to /dev/null messages for specific devices?

Comment: If the driver is free software, you might patch it to remove these errors

Comment: well my tv-card seems to use the kernel module "dvb-usb-pctv452e".

Comment: Downloaded the Kernel-Sources as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Traditional_compilation#Download_the_kernel_source. Never modified a Kernel module, will try it though.

Comment: Modifiying the module worked - Problem solved.